# Django return successful/failure after processing POST data

Tags: python, django

How do I let client side know that Django has processed POST data successfully or not? If yes, it will reset the current views, if not it should raise a notification alert.

```
def test_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        newgroup = request.POST["group"]
        print "Received result"
        # assert validateGroup(newgroup)
        t = Trial(group = newgroup, time = timezone.now(), subject = request.user)
        t.save()

    return render_to_response('interface/test.html',\
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is what I did, but definitely there's no try and catch block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Django messages framework

> Quite commonly in web applications, you need to display a one-time
>   notification message (also known as “flash message”) to the user after
>   processing a form or some other types of user input.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/messages/

Alternatively, you can add an extra variable to your template and display errors in the page.

```
def test_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            # form-processing code
        except ValueError:
            # go back to previous page and show errors
            return render(request, 'previous_page.html',
                {'errors'=['Problem!']})

    # this will be rendered when above exception is not encountered
    return render_to_response('interface/test.html',\
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And in the template (`previous_page.html`), you can do this:

```jinja2
{% for err in errors %}
    <div class="error-box">
        { err }
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Where the `error-box` class highlights your error messages as dismiss-able notifications or however you want to show it.